# Using PIC18F4520 to measure slow period/Frequency

Tags: frequency, counter

I have been trying to find a solution to measuring a relatively slow frequency using the PIC18F4520. The frequency range I'm attempting to measure is in the range of .5 to 20Hz. I need to have a 1 decimal place resolution.

The code I've been attempting to use is not producing results. When I use the variable 'period' unsigned integer, I get all zeroes. If I attempt to use the variable 'result' float, I receive bad data. I am relatively new to using CCP but because of the slow frequency, I felt this would be the best solution.

How can I measure a relatively slow frequency of 0.5 to 20Hz with a resolution of 0.1 Hz with the PIC timers?

```
//PIC18F4520
//Using CX8 ver 1.40

#include<stdio.h>
#include”lcd.h”
#pragma config OSC = XT // XTAL = 4MHZ External
#pragma config WDT = OFF

void InitGPIO()
 {
    DelayMS(10); // POWER UP DELAY
    TRISCbits.TRISC2 = 1; // CCP1 : CONFIGURE AS INPUT PIN
    ADCON1 = 0x0F ;
    TRISD = 0x00;
    TRISE = 0x00;
 }
 void CCPInit()
 {

 T3CON = 0X81;
 CCP1IE = 0;
 CCP1IF = 0;
 T1CON = 0X81;
 CCP1CON = 0x05;

 }
 void main()
 {
 unsigned char string[10];
 unsigned int start,end,period;
 float result,Frequency ;
 InitGPIO();
 InitLCD();

CCPInit();
 LCDString((char *)”Frequency Period”);
while(1)
 {
 while(!(CCP1IF)); // Wait First Rising Edge
 CCP1IF = 0; // Clear Flag Not Next Round
 start = CCPR1; // Save Value of First Rising Edge

while(!(CCP1IF)); // Wait Second Rising Edge
 CCP1CON = 0x00 ; // Disable CCP1 Capture Module
 end = CCPR1; // Save Value of Second Rising Edge

 period = end-start; // Subtract end – Start
 period = (float)period;
//Also attempted 
    //results = end-start;
    //results = (float)results;
    //Frequency = (1/results );     
 Frequency = (1/period );

LCDGotoxy(1,0);
 sprintf(string,”%.3gKHz”,Frequency);
 LCDString(string);

sprintf(string,”%.3gms”,period);
 LCDGotoxy(1,10);
 LCDString(string);
 }
 while(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a short example:

```
//global variables
volatile unsigned char _rfreq_counting = 0; //'0' frequency counter is counting. '1' frequency counter is not counting = available
volatile uint32_t _freq;                    //total frequency
volatile uint16_t _freq_msw;                            //to display the msw

//isr
void interrupt isr(void) {
    //INT interrupt
    if (INTF) {
        INTF = 0;                           //reset the flag
        if (_rfreq_counting == 0) {         //counter isn't current counting -> start counting
            TMR1ON = 1;                     //start the counter
            _freq = 0;                      //TMR1H = TMR1L = 0;        //reset the counters
            _rfreq_counting = 1;            //counting in progress
        } else {                            //timer is already counting -> needs to stop it
            TMR1ON = 0;                     //stop the timer
            _freq |= (TMR1H << 8) | TMR1L;  //store freq
            _freq_msw = _freq >> 16;
            TMR1H = TMR1L = 0;              //reset all counters
            _rfreq_counting = 0;            //counting is done
        }
        IO_FLP(LED_PORT, LED);              //flip led - debug only
    }

    //timer interrupt
    if (TMR1IF) {                           //counter overflow
        TMR1IF = 0;                         //reset the flag
        _freq += 0x10000ul;                 //increment _freq - 16bit timer
    }   

}

//initialize the freq meter
void rfreq_init(void) {
    _rfreq_counting = 0;                    //reset status flag -> not counting

    IO_IN(FREQ_DDR, FREQ_IN);               //FREQ as input pin

    //initialize INT interrupt
    INTEDG = 0;                             //'0'=falling edge, '1'=rising edge
    INTF = 0;                               //clera the flag
    INTE = 1;                               //enable interrupt

    _freq = 0;                              //reset the counter-32bit

    //initialize timer1
    //TMR1ON = 0;                               //stop the timer
    T1CON = 0;                              //count on Fosc/4, counter stop'd, prescaler = 1:1
    TMR1H = TMR1L = 0;                      //reset the counter
    TMR1IF = 0;                             //clear the flag
    TMR1IE = 1;                             //enable interrupt
    //timer not yet started

    PEIE = 1;                               //enable periopheral interrupts
}


int main(void) {

    mcu_init();                             //initialize the mcu
    IO_OUT(LED_DDR, LED);                   //led as output
    rfreq_init();                           //reset the freq counter
    ei();                                   //enable global interrupts
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

rfreq_init() sets up two things:
1. the INT on falling edge (the code works on rising edge as well);
2. timer1 to count FOSC/4.

the ISR does two things:
1. if the tmr1 overflows, it advances _freq by 0x10000ul - timer1 is a 16 bit timer.
2. if the INTF is set -> we should either start the timer or to stop it.

a pin (LED on RA0) is flipped for debug purposes.

_freq contains the value of the count. _freq_msw is pure for simulation as the simulator I'm using doesn't display the 32-bit time correct.
_freq_counting takes value of 1 (the counter is counting so _freq value isn't reliable) or 0(the counter isn't counting so _freq value is reliable -> some exceptions to that, see below).

as _freq is a 32-bit type, you should double read it to maintain atomicity.

The resolution of this approach depends on the crystal used - frequency. with a 4Mhz crystal, you get a resolution of 1Mhz / 2^32 = ...., well beyond what you will typically use.

Note: I was lazy in using a 32-bit type. for the same results, a 16-bit type works, with slightly different programming. or better resolution if you opt to a 32-bit _freq + TMR1H | TMR1L.

[image]

here, a 5Hz pulse train is applied to the RA2/INT pin. the MCU runs on a 4Mhz oscillator so we should expect the counting _freq to be 4Mhz / 4 * 0.2 = 200K.

we will stop the execution right after _freq has been calculated in the ISR:
[image]

you see _freq_msw = 3, and _freq = 3393 - remember the simulator cannot display 32-bit type correct so 3393 is the lowest 16 bits. as such, the real _freq = 3 * 64K + 3393 = 200,001. Off the expected value by 1.

The beauty of this approach is that it runs entirely in the background (through the isr) so your main loop can do whatever it wants.

Porting it to your mcu should be easy.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for such a concise answer. I will test using the example you've outlined. I have done a lot of searching to find some clues about this approach. Again, thank you....

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably doing exactly what its meant to be doing. Try this to confirm:

1. Remove this line: `period = (float)period;`. period is not a float so that's not going to work.
2. Change this line: `Frequency = (1/period );` to this, `Frequency = (1.0/period );` to perform floating point division (otherwise Frequency will always be zero).
3. Change this line: `sprintf(string,”%.3gms”,period);` to this `sprintf(string,”%u,%u”,start, end);`. You can't use the `g` format specify for an unsigned int. The compiler would have surely warned you about that.

Now what do you get on the LCD for start and end? If they're both the same, then the code is working fine, and period should indeed be zero.

To find out why, check the signal on the CCP1 input pin (it may be changing quicker than you expect) and check the speed of your timer (it may not be incrementing a quickly as you think).

Comment: Hi Heath- Thank you for the quick response. I did as you suggested and the start period and end period are different as expected. Calculated results are indeed correct!! However, I can't seem to get the sprintf(string,"%.4u",Frequency); to to compile. Throws a syntax error. Do I need too change the format now? Thank you for your help.

Comment: %u is for unsigned ints. Try %.4f for floats. Google printf for more info

Comment: Thank you Heath. I did realize my error, however, I believe this approach won't work. Anything below ~17Hz and the results become unreliable. I'm hoping that using the gated approach dannyf suggested might yield better results. I'm new to uP so I'll need to stumble a bit to solve this little project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the input pulse train to gate counting of internal frequencies.

The opposite of a typical frequency counter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion dannyf - Since I'm relatively new to PIC programming can you provide an example? While I do understand the basic principle of your suggestion, I'm not sure how to apply.

Comment: Sure. When I get sometime, I will write up something quick fire you.